# WPF Binding Dependency Property to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, dependency-properties

I've got a user control that has a dependency property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MasterListProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MasterList", typeof(IEnumerable<MyObject>), typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(MasterListChanged)));
```

My object implements INotifyPropertyChanged. I'm trying to bind this dependency property to an `ObservableCollection` of that object. however I'm not getting any update when I add an item to my root collection that this dependency property is bound to.

Here's the control that is binding this dependency property to my collection:

```
<image:MyControl MasterList="{Binding Path=SourceList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></image:MyControl>
```

I've tried putting `Mode=TwoWay` and still don't get any update to my Dependency property. I have a tooltip that's bound to the dependency property count and it gets updated, however my `MasterListChanged` event isn't getting fired.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you ever change `SourceList`? if MasterListChanged is not called, then i think the answer is "no"

Comment: Your PropertyChangedCallback won't be called when a MyObject is added to the ObservableCollection. It will only be invoked when the dependency property is set to a new IEnumerable<MyObject> (ObservableCollection<MyObject>).

Comment: @ASh When I add an item, I'm adding it to SourceList

Comment: @mm8 So I'm still not getting an INotifyPropertyChanged event firing when I add a new item to SourceList. Is it because I'm binding to a full ObservableCollection?

Comment: @James, When you add an item to `SourceList`, `SourceList` reference stays the same, binding won't detect any change and won't call PropertyChangedCallback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> however I'm not getting any update when I add an item to my root collection that this dependency property is bound to.

You are not supposed to. The `PropertyChangedCallback` of a dependency property is only invoked when the dependency property *itself* is set to a new value. It won't be called when you add a `MyObject` to the source collection.

What you could do is to handle the `CollectionChanged` event for the collection if you want to do something when an item is added or removed from it, e.g.:

```
private static void MasterListChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var newCol = e.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
    if (newCol != null)
    {
        newCol.CollectionChanged += Coll_CollectionChanged;
    }

    var oldCol = e.OldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
    if (oldCol != null)
    {
        oldCol.CollectionChanged -= Coll_CollectionChanged;
    }
}

private static void Coll_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //do something...
}
```

Comment: Would recommend to change casting statements to `e.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged` and `e.OldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged`

Comment: @SharadaGururaj What's the reasoning behind that?

Comment: INotifyCollectionChanged is less specific than ObservableCollection<MyObject>, i.e. the same code works with more than one type. I updated the answer.

Comment: @James: As a best practice, if you are implementing a custom collection based dependency property on UI - it is recommended that you don't tightly couple it to a specific item-type (model). Similarly, I would recommend that you change the property type from IEnumerable<MyObject> to IEnumerable.

Comment: @SharadaGururaj So this means that all of the properties I need to interact with in the collection changed event must be static? That seems crazy. Am I going about this the wrong way?